# How to TP-Link Archer A9 wireless router to a Verizon Jetpack MiFi 7730L via USB C and keep the power going to the MiIFi?

Tags: router, hotspot

Can a TP-Link Archer A9 wireless router be connected to a Verizon Jetpack MiFi 7300 hotspot (our Internet source)?

There is no Ethernet plug on the hotspot. The WPS option did not connect them.

- The hotspot has a USB C connection for its power.
- The TP-Link Archer A9 router has an Ethernet input.
- A USB C to combination Ethernet and USB C adapter ([Belkin INC001](https://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-INC001/)) didn’t work.
- A USB C to just Ethernet adapter did work, but there is no power to the hotspot when doing it that way. How do I keep it charged?

I’m just trying to simply extend the Wi-Fi signal of the hotspot through the router since other less expensive extenders didn’t work well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A Wi-Fi extender that surprisingly solved the problem and allowed power to stay on my hotspot, was the  “[TP-Link N300 Wi-Fi Range Extender (TL-WA850RE)](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/range-extender/tl-wa850re/).”

That also enabled internet to the TP-Link Deco M9 mesh system via ethernet at the same time. Thanks to Nancy (my girlfriend) who had the final solution, and [Giacomo1968](https://superuser.com/users/167207/giacomo1968).

Comment: Great work! But who is Nancy?

Comment: girlfriend.  i had the small extender ethernet cable to router idea, but it didn’t work.  she suggested retrying the mesh option using the same ethernet from the small extender idea.  viola!  

Comment: “She suggested retrying the mesh option using the same ethernet from the small extender idea.” Listen to women!

Comment: my answer error above, it should have read “That also enabled internet to the TP-Link Deco M9 mesh system via ethernet at the same time”.  sorry.